# Python: Why is this recursion failing?

Tags: python, recursion

Why am I getting maximum recursion results of `[]` in this simple recursion example?

```
# generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                    'parent': [np.nan, 1, 2, 2, np.nan, 1, 1, 5]})

parents = df.parent.dropna().unique().astype(int)
```

```
def find_parent(init_parent):
    init_parent = [init_parent] if isinstance(init_parent, int) else [init_parent]
    if len(init_parent) == 0:
        return init_parent
    else:
        return find_parent(df.loc[df['parent'].isin(init_parent)]['id'].tolist())

# max recursion of [] results
find_parent(parents[1])
```

Comment: `init_parent = [init_parent] if isinstance(init_parent, int) else [init_parent]` read that again, both condition leads to same value

Comment: The recursion ends only when `len(init_parent) == 0` is true, which returns an empty list.  There is no way for this code to return any other result.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def find_parent(init_parent):
    init_parent = [init_parent] if isinstance(init_parent, int) else [init_parent]
    if len(init_parent) == 0:         # this only returns true on an empty array
        return init_parent            # you're getting [] because this return
    else:
        return find_parent(df.loc[df['parent'].isin(init_parent)]['id'].tolist())

# run ops
find_parent(df.loc[df['parent'].isin(init_parent)]['id'].tolist())
```

your maximum return is reached when there is no parent. You overwrite the init parent in the line above, check if it's an empty array, and then return that empty array.

Comment: I don't see any fix

Comment: He didn't ask for one. He asked why it didn't work.

Comment: So you just copy/past his exact same code ? That is the first every, on 5 years, that i see someone just saying the issue, without solving it

Comment: I commented the lines in the code that led to the error along with why it's an issue